# Multiple lines appear on my screen

Tags: graphics-card, display

I was just playing a graphics intense game (need for speed), and suddenly I get a BSOD.  The BSOD doesn't seem normal because of the lines running up and down my screen.

here is a picture (note the green is really white (or maybe I just can't see it right...)

[image: the picture]

What happened?

EDIT: I went to my Nvida control panel, and it said I didn't have a Nvida card attached.  I definately do.
EDIT: In device manager, I right clicked on my Nvidia GeForce8500 GT and under device status, it said "Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)"

EDIT: Windows 7 32-bit I have the Nvida 8500 GT

EDIT: The lines are stuck, but only when the monitor is on, and plugged in.

Comment: Do you have another monitor to try out?

Comment: I had something similar happen with an ATI card (but the effect looked almost identical as in this screenshot) several years ago, the card was dying and needed to be replaced. It was still under warranty so the shop just gave me a new one.

Comment: Its clear.  There is something wrong with the card, I am going to guess, it was hardware failure.  What operating system, what card, and the BSOD does not change what is picture perfectly clear.

Comment: Just got off the phone w/ tech support.  It is the card. Add that as a answer and you'll get the check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see these artifacts at all times (including during POST, boot, and in Windows), then it's a hardware issue and your graphics card may be on its way out. Usually things like this indicate damage of some sort. Different types of artifacts like this can mean different parts of the card are going out (like memory, or different parts of the GPU).

[This site](http://www.playtool.com/pages/artifacts/artifacts.html) has example screenshots of different types of artifacts from various types of graphics card failures. However, if you are not comfortable with going in and fixing it manually, it might be time for a new graphics card.

Comment: These pictures are accurate, however... can this be caused by software?

Comment: @wizlog In your situation, I doubt it would be. You can create any image you want using software, but with your reported symptoms, it appears to be a hardware problem.

Comment: Yes but they started when I was using graphics intensive software.  BTW... I left my computer off over the weekend, and on Monday, it worked normally.  I launched the game, then got another BSOD, and more graphics problems.  P.S. I can't use the site you provided, because my computer can't recognize my graphics card.

Comment: Software may affect hardware. If the effect wasn't immediate to launching the game, it sounds like you had put the graphics card under load and the heat output may have affected its operation (such as warping the card and causing connections to separate). If the effect was immediate, there may just be something wrong with a particular path in the graphics card that games use, but normal operations don't stress. Either way, the behavior ultimately points to a hardware problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Check the temperatures**

Download [FurMark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) and see till what temperature it can get, **STOP if it goes too high**. This depends on your video card, so you got to search into the specifications what the maximum allowed temperature is of your card...

Comment: I'm getting the error: "Could not initialize ZoomGPU. FurMark startup failed. Bye!"

Comment: @wizlog: And as administrator?

Comment: Same (but I think avast antivirus is interfering with its start-up, I told it to always allow the program to run; then right clicked, and clicked on "Run as Administrator")

Comment: Get rid of Avast.