# HD 6970 Corrupted Video

Tags: drivers, video, bios, vga, amd-radeon

Considering this rig:

- i7 2600K
- 8GB RAM Corsair Vengeance kit 10-9-10-27 @1866
- HD 4870
- PSU Corsair AX 1200

I recently upgraded to a HD 6970 and I am getting the following not so nice screens (click to zoom in):

[image]  [image]  [image]

Has anyone any similar trouble at all? I am thinking that the card is DOA but could it also be the Mobo? Since I am in the BIOS I can't think how the mobo could be the problem. HD 4870 works perfect btw regardless of what I throw at it.

Is there any way to prove that the card is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines are called artifacts.  for more info, and maybe ideas on how to fix, see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/328389/multiple-lines-appear-on-my-screen) related question.

To prove its OK, plug it into another compatable motherboard.